# Output stream from remote server bash script to html page line by line

Tags: javascript, php, bash

I am attempting to output the stream from my bash script to my html page line by line. I have been searching up on how this can be done. Currently, my code below works, however, it will wait until my bash script has completed before it outputs the whole thing on to the page, which takes about a couple minutes. I would like the user to see the output real time line by line so they know what is going on. Basically, what the user does is, they click a radio button on the webpage and it launches myFirstScript.sh or mySecondScript.sh, the script will run on a remote sever and output the stream back to the user. I am not able to get this to work with my code below, if someone knows a way please let me know.

myPage.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <style>
    .box1 form {
        width: 450px;
        border: 2px solid black;
        margin: 0;
        display: flex;
    }

    .col {
        display: inline-block;
        border-right: 2px solid black;
        padding: 5px;
        width: 200px;
    }

    .col:last-child {
        border-right: none;
    }

    input[type=text], select {
            width: 20%;
            padding: 12px 20px;
            margin: 8px 0;
            display: inline-block;
                border: 1px solid #ccc;
                border-radius: 4px;
                box-sizing: border-box;
                background-color: #ffffff;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="gatewayInput">
  <form> 
      <input type="text" id="gateway" name="gateway" action="testexe.php" method="POST" placeholder="Gateway Name"><br><br>
  </form>
</div>
<div class="box1">
<form method="post">
<label class="col">Up/Down</label>
<span class="col">
  <input type="radio" name="option" id="r1" value="1" />
  <label for="r1">Up</label>
  <input type="radio" name="option" id="r2" value="2" />
  <label for="r2">Down</label> 
</span>
<span class="col">
  <input type="submit" class="button"/>
</span>
</form>
</div>
    <script src ="../../../jqueryDir/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(".button").click(function(event){
        if ((document.getElementsByName("gateway")[0].value == '')) {
               alert('Gateway Required!');
        return false;
    }
        else if (document.querySelectorAll('input[type="radio"]:checked').length < 1) {
               alert('Please Choose Up/Down Value!');
               return false;
        } 
        else {
               //alert('Sucess!');
            event.preventDefault();
            $.ajax({
            url:"testexe.php",
            type: "POST",
                    data: {option: $('input[type=radio]:checked').val()},
            dataType: "text", 
            success:function(result){
                        $('#div1').html(result)
            }
            });
             return true;
        }
  });
    </script>
<div id="div1"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

testexe.php

```
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST'){
 if ($connection = @ssh2_connect($gateway, 22)) {
           ssh2_auth_password($connection, $gwUser, $gwPwd);
           if(isset($_POST['option']) && $_POST['option'] == 1) { 
                $stream = ssh2_exec($connection, "/home/mydirectory/myFirstScript.sh");
                stream_set_blocking($stream, true);
                $stream_out = ssh2_fetch_stream($stream, SSH2_STREAM_STDIO);
                $stream_err = ssh2_fetch_stream($stream, SSH2_STREAM_STDERR);
                while($line = fgets($stream_out)) {flush(); ob_flush(); echo '<pre>' . $line . '</pre>';}
                echo '<pre>' . "------------------------\n" . '</pre>';
                while($line = fgets($stream_err)) {flush(); ob_flush(); echo '<pre>' . $line . '</pre>';}
                fclose($stream);

           }

           if(isset($_POST['option'])  && $_POST['option'] == 2) { 
                $stream = ssh2_exec($connection, "/home/mydirectory/mySecondScript.sh");
                stream_set_blocking($stream, true);
                $stream_out = ssh2_fetch_stream($stream, SSH2_STREAM_STDIO);
                $stream_err = ssh2_fetch_stream($stream, SSH2_STREAM_STDERR); 
                while($line = fgets($stream_out)) {flush(); ob_flush(); echo '<pre>' . $line . '</pre>';}
                echo '<pre>' . "------------------------\n" . '</pre>';
                while($line = fgets($stream_err)) {echo '<pre>' . $line . '</pre>';ob_flush();flush();}
                fclose($stream);
           }

     }
}
```

myFirstScript.sh

```
#!/bin/bash

echo 'expect -f ./scripts/thisIsMyExpectscript.exp'  #this will call another script and output to the console
expect -f ./scripts/thisIsMyExpectscript.exp         #this will call another script and output to the console
echo
```

mySecondScript.sh

```
#!/bin/bash

for (( c=1; c<=1000000; c++ ))
do
   echo 'Welcome' $c 'times'
done
echo
```

Comment: you need to include the code that is in the bash scripts that are called, i.e. `"/home/mydirectory/mySecondScript.sh"`. . Good luck.

Comment: @shellter I added the bash scripts contents, basically it just a lot of output back to the user i want them to see it line by line.